# Is it possible to know the user that installed a specific package?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, users, dpkg

I don't feel easy with Unix package tools, and I wonder whether it is possible in Ubuntu to list all installed packages and the users who installed them?

Comment: Normally packages are installed only by root. It may look like a user does it, using `sudo`, but when you invoke `sudo id`, you'll see that the effective user then is still root. I would be surprised if `apt` or `dpkg` goes all the way trying to figure out whether it is run genuinely by root or via `su` or `sudo` from another user to then log or persist this anywhere.

Comment: Damn! I see. Thank you for your answer. So I will have to check manually what package I might have installed myself :)

Comment: `sudo(1)` keeps some sort of log of who is doing what...

Answer (score 2):

You can find the manually installed packages in Ubuntu by:

```
# cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep 'apt-get install '
```

Only root can install the packages -- or -- a user who has been given rights in sudoers file for this purpose. In order to find the user who installed those packages, you need to parse the sudoers log. You will find all the commands run by sudo users and therefore the installation commands too.

Comment: I have already found some solutions like yours, but actually it do not differentiate an installation I made and an installation that another user made.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: This is an Useless Use Of Cat, you can simplify it: `grep 'apt-get install ' /var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: it is just for style , it is one time command , so there is no performance issue

Comment: you can check log messages for knowing the details of the installation.